# concat a for loop - php

Tags: php

I want to concatenate a for loop

```
$stringd = "xxx". for($i=1;$i<=$_POST['cc'];$i++) { echo $_POST[$i]." ";} . "hello";
```

The above throws an error; how do I write one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$stringd = "xxx";
for($i=1;$i<=$_POST['cc'];$i++) 
{ 
   $stringd .= $_POST[$i]." ";
} 
$stringd .= "hello";
```

Answer (score 5):

You first have to initialize your string :

```
$stringd = "xxx";
```

Then, loop, concatenating at the end of that variable :

```
for($i=1;$i<=$_POST['cc'];$i++) {
    $stringd .= $_POST[$i]." ";
}
```

And, finally, end with the last part :

```
$stringd .= "hello";
```

But you cannot do all *(especially, the loop)* that in a single operation.

Comment: I would go for the implode if your concatenating the whole post array.

Comment: Indeed ; but not sure he's trying to concatenate the whole array : he's not looping until `count($_POST)`, but until `$_POST['cc']` -- seems a bit odd, though...

Comment: jump seems odd :) i would guess new to coding. Or hes actually saving a delimiter/max count in CC.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo in my answer, but now that I see it is identical to yours (except the "+") :) sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
$stringd = "xxx";

for($i=1;$i<=$_POST['cc'];$i++) 
{ 
   stringd.= $_POST[$i]." ";
} 

$stringd .= "hello";
```