# Create variable in whileloop and use out of the loop

Tags: php, string, variables, while-loop

I would like to use a variable that's created in the while loop outside of it.
It's because I have different variables that I would like to put after eachother (comma seperated) and put in into a string variable. After that I will remove the last comma.

This is my code

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$_POST['moduleName']);   

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {

          //read fieldnames from database
          $fieldName = $row['modFieldName'];

          //creating a variable with the fieldname    
          $fieldName = 'field'.$fieldName;

          //fill Variable with posted input
          $fieldName = $_POST[$row['modFieldName']];

//Put fieldname in a string (outputs: a,b,c,d,e,)
          $postString = $fieldName.","; 

        }
//Remove last comma      
$postString = substr($postString,0,-1);
         echo $postString;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [concat a for loop - php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278663/concat-a-for-loop-php)

Answer (score 0):

So concatenate the result each time, instead of overwriting the string:

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$_POST['moduleName']);

    $postString = ''; 

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      //read fieldnames from database
      $fieldName = $row['modFieldName'];

      //creating a variable with the fieldname    
      $fieldName = 'field'.$fieldName;

      //fill Variable with posted input
      $fieldName = $_POST[$row['modFieldName']];

      //Put fieldname in a string (outputs: a,b,c,d,e,)
      $postString = $postString.$fieldName.","; 
    }

    //Remove last comma      
    $postString = substr($postString, 0, -1);
    echo $postString;
```

Or you could use `.=`. Also, don't use the `mysql_` extensions - they've begun the deprecation process, and can easily lead to SQL injection holes. PDO is a great alternative, as seen below. Finally, **definitely don't put user-supplied data directly into queries**! Yikes!

```
$query = $database->query('SELECT * FROM ' . $moduleName); # Please filter $moduleName against a list of known safe tables!

$postStrings = array_map(function($row) {
    return $_POST['field' . $row->modFieldName];
}, $query->fetchAll());

$postString = implode(',', $postStrings);
```